# custom pagination error when page in start or finish page for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Now im doing custom template on wordpress. And i making custom pagination. i do alot of hardcode for making pagination with on my one. everything is fine if the pagination on second or third page. but hit error when in start number of page or end number of page.

here is the code

```
function list_pagination($Posts) {
   $big = 999999999;
   $paged = paginate_links(array(
       'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
       'format' => '?paged=%#%',
       'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
       'prev_next'          => false,
       'type'               => 'array',
       'add_fragment'       => '',
       'before_page_number' => '',
       'after_page_number'  => '',
       'total' => $Posts->max_num_pages
   ));

    if ( ! empty( $paged ) ) :
                echo '<ul class="pager_list">';
                    $no = 1;
                     foreach ( $paged as $page_link ) :
                         if ( strpos( $page_link, 'current' ) !== false ) { $active = ' active'; }else{ $active = "";}
                            $anchor = new SimpleXMLElement($page_link);
                            echo '<li class="pager_item"><a href="'.$anchor['href'].'" class="pager_link'.$active.'"><span>'.$no.'</span></a></li>'; 
                        $no++;
                    endforeach;
                echo '</ul>';
            endif;

}
```

when the page number on start of number page or end of number page. it display error like this

```
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Entity 'hellip' not defined in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;span class=&quot;page-numbers dots&quot;&gt;&amp;hellip;&lt;/span&gt; in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                         ^ in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php(23): SimpleXMLElement-&gt;__construct('&lt;span class=&quot;pa...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\column.php(143): list_pagination(Object(WP_Query))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(98): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\templateme\functions.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

Comment: Why on earth would `SimpleXMLElement` be involved in something like this in the first place? Massively unclear what you are actually trying to do here. What is so special about your “custom” pagination, that it would require this approach of re-parsing already created HTML?

Comment: because i really want to get the value of href attribut.

Comment: Yes, but why would you need it this way in the first place? What output `paginate_links` creates, is configurable in quite a lot of aspects. So what specific result do you want to achieve here, that would make such extra steps necessary in the first place?

Comment: It appears to be complaining about the HTML entity `&hellip;` here, so you could simply go and replace that with `…` (that is what the entity represents to begin with) before you feed the data to the SimpleXMLElement constructor.

Comment: SimpleXMLElement is totally unnecessary. `paginate_links()` already returns a list. Just change `'type' => 'array'` to `'type' => 'list'`.

Comment: And, of course, get rid of all UL and LI code and just echo `$paged` inside your conditional block.